# PHP array getting duplicate values

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on displaying information from my database. When I did print_r in the model/itemTile.php below to check on my array, $this->display, I noticed it had stored 2 copies of the data from my database. I checked my database, and there was definitely only one copy of the data.

I created a counter variable, $this->counter, to see what the surrounding while loop was doing. The original data had 6 non-duplicating rows. As you may see in the jpg attached below, the program increments and echo the counter to 6, then it does the "print_r($this->display)" line that is outside of the while loop, then for some strange reason goes back to the while loop, increment the counter, and print the $this->counter and $this->display again!

I can remove the duplicate, but I would much prefer to figure out why exactly there are two copies of the value to begin with.

Since this was originally a PHP class project that focus on MVC, everything is placed into controller, model, and view. I have included the relevant model and view code below:

Jpg:
[PHP Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AszS.png)

model/itemTile.php

```
<?php 
    require_once('siteInfo.php');

    class itemTile implements siteInfo {
        private $term;
        private $session;
        private $result;
        private $display = array();
        private $counter = 0;

        public function __construct($session) {
            $this->session = $session;
        }

        public function getContent() {
            $this->result = $this->session->db->prepare("SELECT productName, sciName, price FROM products");
            $this->result->execute();
            $this->result->bind_result($pN, $sN, $pz);
            while ($this->result->fetch()) {
                if (array_key_exists($pN, $this->display)) {
                    $this->display[$pN]["price"][] = $pz;
                } else {
                    $this->display += [
                        $pN => [         //Product Name was used to id array because not all item have sciName,
                            "sciName" => [$sN],  //and not all item have only 1 sku (1 item with different size = multiple pid).
                            "price" => [$pz]
                        ]
                    ];
                }
                $this->counter++;
                echo $this->counter . "<br />";
            }
            $this->result->close();
            print_r($this->display);
            echo "<br />";
        }

        public function setContent() {
            $this->getContent();
            return $this->display;
        }
    }
?>
```

view/itemTile.php

```
<?php 
class itemTileView {
    private $model;

    public function __construct(itemTile $model) {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function output(){
        foreach ($this->model->setContent() as $item => $detail) {
            $itemLink = preg_replace('/\s+/','_', $item);
            echo "<div class= 'tileSpace'>";
            echo "<a href='itemPages/" . $itemLink. "/home.php'>";
            echo "<img alt='" . $item . "' src='itemPages/" . $itemLink . "/thumbnail.jpg' width='100' height='100'>";
            echo "</a>";
            echo "<p>" . $item . ": " . $detail["sciName"][0] . "</p>";
            if (count($detail["price"]) > 1) {
                echo "<p>" . min($detail["price"]). " - " . max($detail["price"]). "</p>"; 
            } else {
                echo "<p>" . $detail["price"][0] . "</p>"; 
            }
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Can anyone spot where is the problem occurring?

Comment: Well, we're missing a piece of the puzzle. In your examples you're not calling output anywhere. It'd be nice to see that as well. Otherwise I'm gonna go out on a limb and say that you're calling `setContent()` twice. That is why you'd go through the loop twice but only have one row of images.

Comment: Thank you so much! I went through the other related files looking for setContent(), and it turns out I did a setContent() in my Controller file, then I tried to display the resulted array in the View file by calling setContent() again instead of the actual array! setContent() returns the array, but it also runs the getContent() again. It is working correctly now!

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

use php function array_unique();

```
array_unique($arrayname);
```

using this you will get unique values from array.it avoids duplicate values